# Read audit log and display in webpart

Tags: auditing

I want to display audit report in webpart.
Webpart will have a button "get_audit" and dropdown which have months (Jan-Dec). when user select month say Jan and click on button it would display the data in gridview.
Data need to be like name of users (constant user 10) in Y asix and no. of hit in X asix.
It will show data for each day of Jan month for each user's no. of hit of site. Site will be homepage.

I have reffered below site which full fill my half requirement. Can someone provide me code for the same. Thanks

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/431342/Auditing-A-Built-in-Feature-of-SharePoint